# Assigning a Function result as a HTML ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm creating an element dynamically like so:

```
 var el = $.parseHTML("<div><div class=\"content\" id=" + uniqueId + "><div/>");
```

And I'm generating a unique ID for each element:

```
var uniqueId = function () {
return 'id-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
};
```

But on the output when the element is created the ID is literally "Function" ? How would I get the ID to assign the result of the function  instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call function instead of just providing it's name:

```
var el = $.parseHTML("<div><div class=\"content\" id=" + uniqueId() + "><div/>");
```

Comment: oh man arn't I a silly one, thanks :P (Will accept answer when SO lets me)